# how to convert json to row and column format using oracle

Tags: json, json-value, json-arrayagg

{ "Message ": [ { "PACK_NO": "219069571", "COMPONENT_ITEM": [ { "ITEM": "308187417", "PACK_QTY": 2 } ] }, { "PACK_NO": "219069572", "COMPONENT_ITEM": [ { "ITEM": "308187419", "PACK_QTY": 2 } ] }, { "PACK_NO": "219178060", "COMPONENT_ITEM": [ { "ITEM": "308235779", "PACK_QTY": 2 } ] }, { "PACK_NO": "219178061", "COMPONENT_ITEM": [ { "ITEM": "308235775", "PACK_QTY": 1 }, { "ITEM": "308235777", "PACK_QTY": 1 }, { "ITEM": "308235778", "PACK_QTY": 2 }, { "ITEM": "308235779", "PACK_QTY": 2 }, { "ITEM": "308235780", "PACK_QTY": 2 }, { "ITEM": "308235781", "PACK_QTY": 2 } ] } ] }'

Comment: What table format? What have you tried doing? Please use a search engine before asking here.